# CSS: *html #id_name

Tags: css

I have this code

```
*html #alertBox {
    height:100px;
}

#modalContainer > #alertBox {
    position:fixed;
}
```

is this supported by css, i found this code in some other site(I forgot the link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*html #alertBox {
    height:100px;
}
```

That's a mistyped star-HTML. Star-HTML is a CSS hack usually used to target rules at IE6.

The star-HTML prefix in a rule shouldn't match anything, because there is no element (`*`) above the root element (`html`). But it does in IE up to version 6 due to bugs in that browser.

However for this to be a valid rule, there must be a space between the `*` and the `html`. The current code is invalid CSS: the validator will complain and browsers might do unexpected things with it. As it happens, in the current crop of browsers there is no difference: IE6-7 allows the spaceless syntax, the others ignore the whole rule. But you shouldn't really rely on that.

```
#modalContainer > #alertBox {
    position:fixed;
}
```

That's a child selector: it selects the alertBox when it's a direct child of modalContainer.

`>` is something IE6 doesn't understand at all, so the consequence is to target the rule at all browsers except IE6 (which doesn't support `position: fixed`). This makes it more-or-less the opposite of the star-HTML hack. Clearly it is being used for the purpose here, as otherwise the selector, including two unique IDs, is quite redundant.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the [*star HTML hack*](http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/filters/star-html/) and is useful in helping you pass certain CSS rules to older versions of Internet Explorer.

So the first example will only set the height of `#alertBox` to 100 pixels if the browser that is used is susceptible to the star HTML hack:

The second example (`#modalContainer > #alertBox`) will be applied to any element with an ID of `alertBox` which is also a ***direct child*** of another element that has an ID of `modalContainer`.

The markup would have to look something like this:

```
<div id="modalContainer">
    <div id="alertBox"></div>
</div>
```

and not this:

```
<div id="modalContainer">
    <div>
        <div id="alertBox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both of these rules are valid CSS.

Comment: how about the other one the one with the ">" sign

Comment: "`>`" is to indicate direct descendent/child. Use it with caution :P

Comment: so that means i cannot assign the use ">" if it is not a direct child of the parent element??

Comment: To clarify, the `* html` is for IE6, and the `#modalContainer > #alertBox` is for IE7+

Comment: @Treby - `>` selects direct child, so yes, you can't use it otherwise