# Difference between two CSS selectors: why use "* html"?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS: *html #id_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106248/css-html-id-name)

I have a simple CSS question.
What's the difference between these two selectors

```
* html div.body_content{
     height:100%;
}
```

vs

```
div.body_content{
     height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`* html` is a non-standard way of targeting IE6. As html is the root tag the * selector shouldn't work but does in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

`* html` is a hack for IE 6. It is non-standard and because IE 6 treats `HTML` tag as a child of `*`, which it takes as a the root element, we can use this to target IE 6.

Answer (score 1):

Actually
By specifying * in the css means all the tags under .
But in IE6 the is also one tag under * so this type of representation is write for only to solve the problems in IE6